# How to display data in a chart in function of dropdown value using anychart js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, charts, anychart

I'm trying to use anychart js to make line chart. The data displeyed on this chart is data provided from an api and concerns nba players stats. It is provided under JSON format. So what I want is to set the data in function of what I have selected in the dropdown.

For exemple, if I select fga attribute in the dropdown then it will display line chart with fga as data. If choose then fgm it will remove the current line chart and display another one with fgm as data.

Here is my request to the API : https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/stats?seasons[]=2019&player_ids[]=237&per_page=100

Here is the web site : https://www.balldontlie.io

So my problem is when I do that I create several chart for each element of my array. I can make one chart with all this data.

Here is my code :

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    data : {
        choice : "",
        stat : []


},

    methods: {
        statSelect : function(event){
                return axios.get("https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/stats?seasons[]=2019&player_ids[]=237&per_page=100")
                  .then(response => {
                  var tab = response.data.data.map((item) => {
                var date = new Date(item.game.date);
                var dateN = date.toLocaleString('en-US',
                {year : 'numeric', month : 'numeric', day: 'numeric'});
                if (event.target.value == "fga") {

                    this.stat.push([dateN, item.fga]);
              var chart = anychart.line();
              var serie = chart.line(this.stat);
              chart.yScale().minimum(0);
              chart.container("container");
              chart.draw();
                    console.log(this.stat);
                }

                if (event.target.value == "fta") {
                    stat = [dateN, item.fta];

                    console.log(stat);
                }

                else {
                           stat = [dateN, item.ftm];

                    console.log(stat);                  }

                 });
                return stat;
                });
        }
    }})
```

And here is the result : [image]

Regards

YT

Comment: So you want to have one chart that shows different data depending on what's selected in the dropdown and the problem is that you're getting multiple charts? Have a look at [addSeries](https://api.anychart.com/v8/anychart.charts.Cartesian#addSeries) and [removeAllSeries](https://api.anychart.com/v8/anychart.charts.Cartesian#removeAllSeries) for how to change what data is displayed in a chart.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correctly understanding what you're trying to do, here is an example of how you'd do it in vanilla javascript.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  //fetch the data
  const url = "https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/stats?seasons[]=2019&player_ids[]=237&per_page=100";
  const dataPromise = axios.get(url)
    .then(response => response.data.data)
    .catch(reason => alert('GET failed. ' + reason));
  
  //init chart
  const chart = anychart.line();
  chart.defaultSeriesType('line');
  
  //keep chart updated to match dropdown
  const selectElem = document.querySelector('select');
  selectElem.addEventListener('change', event => {
    showChartFor(event.target.value);
  });
  showChartFor(selectElem.value);

  function showChartFor(key) {
    dataPromise.then(data => {
      const series = data.map(item => {
        const date = new Date(item.game.date);
        const dateN = date.toLocaleString('en-US', {
          year: 'numeric',
          month: 'numeric',
          day: 'numeric'
        });
        return [dateN, item[key]];
      });

      chart.removeAllSeries();
      chart.addSeries(series);
      chart.container('container');
      chart.draw();
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.7.1/js/anychart-base.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <select>
    <option value="fga">fga</option>
    <option value="fta">fta</option>
    <option value="ftm">ftm</option>
  </select>
  <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. However I'm actually using viewjs and I would like to know how to implement that with this thechnologie ?

Answer (score 0):

To apply new data to the series there's no need to recreate the chart or even the series. You can simply apply new data to the existing series:

```
// create series
var series = chart.line(initialData);
// apply new data
series.data(newData);
```